# does Template Haskell name quoting desugar 'x to NameG?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Can I always expect the single single-quote syntax to desugar to the `NameG` constructor? e.g. does

```
'x
```

always desugar to

```
(Name (OccName "x") (NameG VarName (PkgName "some-package") (ModName "SomeModule")))
```

This information must always be there, after name resolution, which is the stage Template Haskell runs after, right? And I haven't been able to quote local names, though I'm only interested in quoting top-level names.

Context: I want to write a function that returns the uniquely-qualified identifier. It's a partial function because I can't constrain the input, as Template Haskell doesn't have any GADTs or anything, while I don't want to wrap the output in uncertainty. And I don't want to use a quasi-quoter or splice, if `'` will do. I want to prove that this partial function is safe at runtime when used as above, **quoting top-level names in the same module**, given:

```
name (Name occ (NameG _ pkg mod)) = Unique occ pkg mod
```

I want to have a function like:

```
(<=>) :: Name -> a -> Named a
```

given:

```
data Named a = Named a Unique
```

to annotate variable bindings:

```
x = 'x
 <=> ...
```

without the user needing to use the heavy splice syntax `$(name ...)`, and invoke splicing at compile time:

```
x = $(name 'x)
 <=> ...
```

The user will be writing **a lot** of these, for configuration.

https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html and https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.8.0.0/docs/src/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#Name didn't say.

(p.s. I'd also like to know if the double single-quote syntax (e.g. `''T`) had the analogous guarantee, though I'd expect them to be the same).

Comment: `let x = () in $(stringE $ Data.Generics.gshow 'x)` evaluates to `"(Name (OccName \"x\") (NameL (1627422417)))"`

Answer (score 1):

Since ' quoted names are known at compile time, why don't you change name to be in the Q monad:

```
name :: Name -> ExpQ
name (Name occ (NameG _ pkg mod)) = [| Unique occ pkg mod |]
name n = fail $ "invalid name: "++ gshow n
```

Then you use  `$(name 'show) :: Unique` instead of `name 'show :: Unique`. If you get an invalid `Name` (say somebody uses `mkName`), that failure will show up at compile time.

Comment: yeah, that's my plan B, it's safer but uglier (and maybe compile-time slower). I edited the question.